# How can I create a Hibernate session without hiberante.cfg.xml file?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate.cfg.xml

This is my first time using `Hiberante`.

I am trying to create a Hibernate `session` within my application using the following:

```
Session session = HiberanteUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
```

It gives me this error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
```

However I do not have a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file within my project.

How can I create a session *without* having this file?

Comment: I want to set hibernate up using just annotations, i.e. in this guide: http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/configure_hibernate_without_hibernate_cfg_xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simples way to configure Hibernate 4 or Hibernate 5

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

Hibernate reads a configuration from `hibernate.cfg.xml` and `hibernate.properties`.

You shouldn't call `configure()`, if you don't want to read `hibernate.cfg.xml`. With adding an annotated class

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(User.class).buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;
import com.concretepage.persistence.User;

public class HibernateUtil {
    private static final SessionFactory concreteSessionFactory;
    static {
        try {
            Properties prop= new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "root");
            prop.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "");
            prop.setProperty("dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");

            concreteSessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration()
           .addPackage("com.concretepage.persistence")
                   .addProperties(prop)
                   .addAnnotatedClass(User.class)
                   .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }
    public static Session getSession()
            throws HibernateException {
        return concreteSessionFactory.openSession();
    }

    public static void main(String... args){
        Session session=getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        User user=(User)session.get(User.class, new Integer(1));
        System.out.println(user.getName());
        session.close();
    }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, do you recommend this way over the other hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: I am confused as to what this means: import com.concretepage.persistence.User; ?

Comment: @java123999 It is your persistent class. You can use any class for this with `@Entity` and `@Table` annotations.

Comment: Hi,java123999
import com.concretepage.persistence.User is for my POJO class.YOU can import your POJO.

This way you can avoid xml file.

Comment: `AnnotationConfiguration` removed from Hibernate 5

Comment: “org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration” is deprecated, and all its functionality has been moved to “org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration“.

So, you can safely replace your “AnnotationConfiguration” with “Configuration” class.

Comment: But why do we mix all these stuff in java class let it be separate xml file file itself